# QQuickWindow context property?

Tags: c++, qt, window, qml

I am creating a new window through the following code:

```
QMainController* myController = new QMainController(0,m_autenticado);
QQmlApplicationEngine* engine = new QQmlApplicationEngine(this);

engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("MyController", myController);
engine->load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///newPage.qml")));

QQuickWindow* window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(engine->rootObjects().at(0));
window->showFullScreen();
```

This code sets a **MyController** property to the rootContext, which means that all the pages at the root context will have access to this property. And so, this won't allow me to open 2 different windows from the same QML file, each with its own instance of MainController.

**QUESTION**: How can I bind this **MyController** property to the QQuickWindow context instead of the engine's rootContext?

I've tried to use a QQuickView and doing like this:

```
QMainController* myController = new QMainController(0,m_autenticado);

QQuickView* view = new QQuickView();
view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("MyController", myController );
view->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));
view->showFullScreen();
```

But I was complained with the following message:

> "QQuickView only supports loading of root objects that derive from QQuickItem.
>
> If your example is using QML 2, (such as qmlscene) and the .qml file you
> loaded has 'import QtQuick 1.0' or 'import Qt 4.7', this error will occur.
>
> To load files with 'import QtQuick 1.0' or 'import Qt 4.7', use the
> QDeclarativeView class in the Qt Quick 1 module."

Comment: To fix the error message, make your root item in main.qml an Item or something derived from it.

Comment: I might be wrong, but this doesn't feel right. I would lose the windows' signals and properties, wouldn't I?

Comment: Yeah, but you'll fix the error message. :p

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`QQuickWindow` does not own any context property of its own so there is no way to set context property with it.

Just like the message explains, `QQuickView` expects a QML root object that is inherited from `QQuickItem`, which means the root can be a `Rectangle`, `Item` etc, but not `ApplicationWindow` or `Window`, since they are not inherited from `QQuickItem`. If you can change root object to something like `Rectangle`, you can create different instances of `QQuickView` to reach your goal, since each `QQuickView` creates its own `QQmlEngine` if you don't provide an existing `QQmlEngine` to it.

`QQmlApplicationEngine` actually inherits from `QQmlEngine`, so each instance has its own root context. For example calling the following `createMain()` twice will create two windows with separate engines, separate controller and separate rootContext:

```
void foo::createMain() {
    //TODO: Set a proper parent to myController
    QMainController* myController = new QMainController(0,m_autenticado);
    QQmlApplicationEngine* engine = new QQmlApplicationEngine(this);

    engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("MyController", myController);
    engine->load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///newPage.qml")));

    QQuickWindow* window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(engine->rootObjects().at(0));
    window->showFullScreen();
}
```

If you don't feel right about creating multiple copies of `QQmlAppicationEngine`, you can share one instance of `QQmlApplicationEngine` instead, and create a child context for each window instance:

```
// foo.h
class foo {
private:
  QQmlApplicationEngine m_engine;  // can change to QQmlEngine if you prefer
}

// foo.cpp
void foo::createMain()
{
  //TODO: Set a proper parent to myController
  QMainController* myController = new QMainController(0,m_autenticado);

  // Create a new context as a child of m_engine.rootContext()
  QQmlContext *childContext = new QQmlContext(&m_engine, &m_engine);
  childContext->setContextProperty("MyController", myController);

  QQmlComponent *component = new QQmlComponent(&m_engine, &m_engine);
  component->loadUrl(QUrl("qrc:///qml/newPage.qml"));

  // Create component in child context
  QObject *o = component->create(childContext);
  QQuickWindow* window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(o);
  window->show();
}
```

And of course you can change `QQmlApplication` to `QQmlEngine` if there's no use of QQmlApplicationEngine's features.